# Limit Teaser to display only the first value of a Field

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have a Content Type with an Image Field. This field will typically be populated with 0 to 4 values. By default the teaser for this Content Type outputs all 0 to 4 images. How can I adjust the Teaser to only display the first image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a custom module, replace `MODULENAME` with the name of the module and `field_image` with the name of your field:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view().
 */
function MODULENAME_entity_view($entity, $type, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'teaser') {
    $entity->content['field_image']['#items'] = array_slice($entity->content['field_image']['#items'], 0, 1);
  }
}
```

See the [hook_entity_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7) documentation for more details.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a try. It may be a couple days before I can implement it and report back. I'm relatively new to writing modules, so I have a couple questions: (1) will your sample code work (not crash) when there are zero values in the field and (2) will it work (not crash) when there are other content types without the Image field? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Yes, it should.
2) You could change the if statement to be `if ($view_mode == 'teaser' && $entity->type == 'CONTENT_TYPE')`.

Comment: Or simply && isset($entity->content['field_image']), then you don't need to update the code when adding the field to another content type or renaming that one, or.. :)

Comment: Hmmm. This might work, but it's an example of putting into code what should be in a theme.

Comment: It will work, but if you solve thinks like this by custom code the site will be less maintainable in the future. Use some module from drupal.org mentioned in other answers instead.

Answer (score 12):

No need to write custom code.

Try using [Field multiple limit](http://drupal.org/project/field_multiple_limit) module.

> It allows you to go into the display settings for your content type
>   and configure the teaser settings to display only a certain amount of
>   values. You can even make it skip vales, for example if you want it to
>   display values 2 to 5

.

Answer (score 4):

If using a teaser template (ie: **node--CONTENT-TYPE--teaser.tpl.php**), this works:

```
  <?php print render($content['IMAGE-FIELD'][0]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used hook_field_extra_fields() and hook_node_view() to create a new field to display the first image so that I wasn't tampering with the original images field.

hook_field_extra_fields() initialises the new field which will appear on the manage display tab of your node type.

```
function HOOK_field_extra_fields() {
  $extra['node']['NODE_TYPE'] = array(
    'display' => array(
      'primary_image' => array(
        'label' => t('Primary Image'),
        'weight' => 0,
      )
    ),
  );
  return $extra;
}
```

Then hook_node_view() is used to add the first image to be the content of your new field.

```
function HOOK_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if($node->type == 'NODE_TYPE' && $view_mode == 'teaser') {

    //make sure there are images
    if(!empty($node->field_images)) {
      $node->content['primary_image'] = $node->content['field_images'][0];

      //hide the original field with multiple images
      hide($node->content['field_images']);
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: If you have display suite enabled you can do this in the manage display tab.